# Spika-Android: "Can't connect to server"

Tags: java, android, connection

I'm am attempting to run Spika-Android and when I try to sign up I get this error.
[image: First error]

Even if the app let me select the Server, it says that it can't connect to server.
I've set this in the admin panel:[image: Information]

This is my Server Constant code:

```
public class ConstServer {

/* Change to your server adress */
public static final String BASE_URL = "http://192.168.1.68:1232/Spika-Server-master/wwwroot/api/";
public static final String SERVER_URL = "http://192.168.1.68:1232/Spika-Server-master/wwwroot";
public static final String INFORMATION_URL   = "http://192.168.1.68:1232/Spika-Server-master/wwwroot/page/information/";
public static final String LIST_SERVERS_URL         = SERVER_URL + "/" + Const.API_FOLDER + "servers";
}
```

Can someone help me, please? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved the problem adding .php at the end of the URL in the Admin Panel!